# Set new session ID when user logs out Express, Socket.io, PassportJS

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io, passport.js

I'm writing a messaging application and I am using Express, Socket.io, PassportJS.

Currently when the user connects they are given a session id.  This gets shared with the websocket. When communications come in through the websocket, I use `socket.request.session` to get the PassportJS info about the session.  From there I deserialize the user and then ensure that they are authorized to perform the action they're attempting.

When a user logs out, if they attempt to send a message, my application crashes because the websocket still has the previous session id even though I destroy it server side.

I don't understand how to give the user a new session id when they log out so that they don't end up crashing the server.

`server.js:`

```
var sessionStore = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: settings.dbUri,
    collection: settings.sessionCollection
});
var sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: settings.sessionSecret,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week 
    },
    store: sessionStore
});
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);
});
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    passport.initialize();
    passport.session();
    next();
});
// Handle routing to applications
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('player.html', {root: __dirname + '/apps/player'});
});

function returnUserOrContinue (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    var user = { user: {
        username: req.user.username
    }};
    res.json(user);
    } else {
    return next()
    }
}

// User API
app.post('/userApi/login',
     returnUserOrContinue,
     passport.authenticate('localSignUp'),
     function(req, res) {
         var user = { user: {
         username: req.user.username
         }};
         res.json(user);
     });

app.post('/userApi/logout', function(req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    req.session.destroy();
    }
    res.send(null);
});

function ifUserLoggedIn(sessionID, callback) {
    sessionStore.get(sessionID, function(err, session){
    if (session && session.passport.user) {
        passport.deserializeUser(session.passport.user, function(err, user) {
        callback(user);
        });
    }
    });
}
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('new socket connection');

    // Admin land
    socket.emit('updateQueue');

    // User Land
    socket.on('syncVideo', function() {
    socket.emit('currentVideoChanged', videoQueue.getCurrentVideoInfo());
    });
    socket.on('sendMessage', function(messageInfo) {
    var sessionID = socket.request.sessionID;
    ifUserLoggedIn(sessionID, function(user) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('newMessage', messageInfo);
    });
    });
});

server.listen(listenPort, '0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log('listening on *:', listenPort);
});
```

`passport.js:`

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var userController = require('./models/user').controller;

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, callback) {
    callback(null, user.id);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, callback) {
    userController.getUserById(id, callback);
    });
    passport.use('localSignUp', new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, next){
        userController.getUserByUsername(username, function(user) {
        if (!user) {
            var newUser = userController.addUser(username, password);
            return next(null, newUser);
        }
        if (!userController.validPassword(user, password)) {
            return next(null, null);
        }
        return next(null, user);
        });
    }
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call req.sesion.regenerate() on logout to generate a new session, which has the new session ID.

```
req.session.regenerate(function(err) {
  // will have a new session here if no error
  res.send(null);
});
```

Comment: you probably want to respond after regenerate() is completed like what I have there.  User might not have the new sessionId if you call res.send() outside of regenerate's callback.

Comment: Sorry my comment wasn't mean to be submitted :P.

How do I propogate this new ID to the socket connection?  Just on the client side set it when the server responds?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can set the sessionID on client side.  I think you can set the session ID for that socket before calling res.send().  Haven't done it before, so I'm not so sure about this.  Or you might have to have client side reconnect the socket with the new sesionId to sync the sessionId

Comment: Yeah manually reconnecting he socket on the client gave the socket the new connection the new session info

Comment: my new session is getting created but the session id is not getting stored in mongo collection store and the session id is also not getting updated in the browser